# Sphinx rtd docs dropdown only works post click

Tags: documentation, python-sphinx, documentation-generation, read-the-docs

I have created an rtd themed documentation for my package using `sphinx` and `sphinx_rtd_theme`. The `index.rst` is as follows:

```
Welcome!

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 1
   :glob:

   src


Indices and tables
==================

* :ref:`genindex`
* :ref:`modindex`
* :ref:`search`
```

And the src file is roughly following this idea:

```
================
Template Project
================
.. automodule:: src
   :members:
   :undoc-members:
   :show-inheritance:

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 4

   features
   io
   model
   utilities
```

The html_theme_options is also as follows in `conf.py`:

```
html_theme_options = {
    "analytics_anonymize_ip": False,
    "logo_only": False,
    "display_version": True,
    "prev_next_buttons_location": "bottom",
    "style_external_links": False,
    "vcs_pageview_mode": "",
    # Toc options
    "collapse_navigation": True,
    "sticky_navigation": True,
    "navigation_depth": 4,
    "includehidden": True,
    "titles_only": False,
    "globaltoc_collapse": True,
    "globaltoc_maxdepth": None,
}
```

The problem I'm expericing right now is that, the drop down's are not working correctly. They don't show up in the sidebar, unless I click on an item that should have a dropdown button near it.

[image: This is without dropdowns]

And after I click on the sidebar link, I will go to the next file which is an opened dropdown.

[image: Opened dropdown.]

What I would like to do is that, I want to have the dropdown option since the first item. This is clunky and unintuitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs for the theme](https://sphinx-rtd-theme.readthedocs.io/en/stable/configuring.html#confval-collapse_navigation), you can set `collapse_navigation = False`.

Comment: I can't believe I've missed this. Thank you so much!